# XML targetNamespace and unqualified declaration of elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I'm somewhat confused as to how the `targetNamespace` attribute in an XML schema affects the naming of elements. I'm getting an error validating the following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="test" version="1.0">
    <xs:element name="testType" type="testType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="testType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="testSubtype" type="testSubType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="testSubType">
        <!-- some fields -->
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XMLSpy is stating it `Cannot resolve the unqualified declaration or definition 'testSubType'.` How can I resolve this? I need to keep the `targetNamespace` attribute in there. I've tried changing `testSubType` to `test:testSubType` in various areas but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either add the `xmlns="test"` attribute to the schema element in order declare that default namespace for this schema is "test" or add `xmlns:t="test"` to declare that `t` is the prefix for the "test" namespace and use that prefix like `type=t:testSubType` when referencing types that you defined in this namespace (which you're doing by saying test is your targetNamespace).

Comment: This answer saved me hours. FYI, I have had more success using the prefixes, since the default namespace can sometimes have other unintended consequences.